# JIRA: Send issue comment notifications after grace period for edits

Tags: jira, email-notifications

I'm subscribed to an issue in JIRA. Whenever someone comments on it, or changes a comment of his, I get an email.
Often this results in multiple consecutive emails, when people enter a comment, and then refine it multiple times.

I'd like to tell JIRA to wait after a new comment before sending me the notification mail, which should then include all modifications to it by the time.

Is this possible?

*I know this question might be better off at superuser, but the jira tag here seems by far more frequented.*

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, when somebody wanna edit his comment there is a tick asking if he wanna notify all the watchers about the edit with the email message or not.

So all you can do is to ask your team to leave comments with 'notify' tick disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can actually disable this autosend notifications through the API from Jira, see documentation : https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/configuring-email-notifications-185729575.html